# Подключить репозиторий с последней версией mySQL (8) для Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysqli, репозиторий

Чистый Ubuntu 16.04. Нужно подключить репозиторий (или как это называется) с mySQL 8, чтобы командой apt-get install установилась последняя версия mySQL, а не 5.7.

Как это сделать?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

Comment: мне нужно добавить репозиторий в Ubuntu не устанавливая mySQL, чтобы эта СУБД версии 8 автоматом поставилась при запуске установщика панели управления сайтами vestaCP. Нужно как-то добавить репозиторий в саму ОС Ubuntu. Не знаю как это делается.